# jQuery Get JSON from HTTP request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to load JSON from other page provided by my server. This is my javascript code:

```
$('#checkprice').click(function(){
  $.get('{{route('userinventory')}}',function(data){
  console.log('test')
},'json');     
});
```

Now, this:

```
  {{route('useriventory)}}
```

Is working fine, it just generate url for me and when I visit it, this is type of data i'm getting:

```
[{"assetid":"8522812062","classid":"720539092","itemname":"\u2605 Bayonet | Doppler (Factory New)","name_color":"8650AC","price":156.34},{"assetid":"8516603597","classid":"721320736","itemname":"\u2605 StatTrak\u2122 M9 Bayonet | Marble Fade (Factory New)","name_color":"8650AC","price":540}]
```

I think my JSON data is fine, url /userinventory hits method that just return json encoded array. When I try to get it in JS it's not working for some reason. First I tried json.get now tried with ajax same result (nothing is happening)

Comment: You should do `console.log(data);` instead.

Comment: @jeroen I don't want to output data, i just want to check if it's working then i'm going to do something with data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the [$.get documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) of jquery. The second parameter is a data parameter. So you code should work like this:

```
    $('#checkprice').click(function(){
       $.get('{{route('userinventory')}}',{},function(data){
          console.log('test')
       },'json');     
    });
```

Comment: Did you replace '{{route('userinventory')}}' with the correct url to the route?

Comment: What does your 'console' say in the developer tools of your browser? Try to follow the request in the 'network' tab of the developer tools in the browser to check if the request is fired to you server correctly. Maybe you got an error back (and didn't specify an error callback in the $.get function)

Comment: Route was working fine but I got error code, it was on php side but now is fixed